# Does IsEmailValid() exist somewhere in Google's Cloud SDK?

Tags: python, google-cloud-sdk

I've rolled my own email validation function before but have a project that uses a Pre-Google-Cloud-SDK api:

`from google.appengine.api.mail import IsEmailValid`

This takes a string and returns True/False if it does/doesn't follow the format for an email address. it doesn't test to see if the email address is live - it only parses the string.

Does this functionality exist in Google's Cloud SDK api?

I suspect not as bulk mail support was dropped from App Engine and, with it, this support function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cloud API does not offer this type of validation. You can actually search all the available methods in the [Client library documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/index.html) and in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python).

If you are deploying your application with Google App Engine, you can always configure the App to handle [Bounce notifications](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/mail/#mail_from_g_suite) in case a mail is not delivered.

Alternatively, Gmail has its own [getProfile API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) that allows you to check if a user is valid, unfortunately it will only work for gmail accounts.